# Coordinate free expression for the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, vector-bundles, determinants

Let $E\rightarrow X$ be a rank two vector bundle on a variety $X$. How can one write an abstract map $Sym^2(E)\rightarrow (\wedge^2 E)^{\otimes 2}$ that in local coordinates, when we fix a frame of $E$, gives the determinant of a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix?

Comment: The vector bundle $\operatorname{Sym}^2E$ is spanned by local sections which are symmetric products $u \cdot v$. Map to $(u\wedge v)^{\otimes 2}$. Extend by linearity. Is that not the sort of answer you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not quite. In local coordinates write $u = ai+bj$ and $v = ci+dj$. Then $u\otimes v = ac (i\otimes i) + ad (i\otimes j) + bc (j\otimes i) + bd (j\otimes j)$, and the corresponding matrix would be $M = (m_{i,j})$ with $m_{1,1} = ac, m_{1,2} = ad, m_{2,1} = bc, m_{2,2} = bd$. Since the map I am looking for should give the determinant of the matrix it should be zero on tensors of type $u\otimes v$. Here i considered the non symmetric case but the same question make sense replacing $E\otimes E$ with $Sym^2(E)$.

Comment: I don't even  think that there is a *natural* map unless you're in characteristic $2$. Otherwise, these correspond to distinct irreducible representations of $GL_2$.

Comment: No, I am in characteristic zero. I am thinking of a quadratic map $Sym^2(E)\rightarrow (\bigwedge^2 E)^{\otimes 2}$. But yes, frankly I am not even sure something like this exists. For instance, I tried starting with the map $E^{\otimes 4}\rightarrow (\bigwedge^2 E)^{\otimes 2}$ mapping $v_1\otimes v_2\otimes v_3\otimes v_4\mapsto (v_1\wedge v_3)\otimes (v_2\wedge v_4)+(v_2\wedge v_3)\otimes (v_1\wedge v_4)$ but it does not seem to induce a map $Sym^2(E)\rightarrow (\bigwedge^2 E)^{\otimes 2}$ with the property I want.

Comment: Why is there the tensor exponent "$\otimes 2$"?  The usual determinant has target $\bigwedge^2 E$, not $(\bigwedge^2 E)^{\otimes 2}$.  Are you asking about the square of the determinant?

Comment: The determinant of a matrix with a fixed frame depends skew-symmetrically (not symmetrically) on the frame, so the source of your map should be $\wedge^2E$. Also, as @JasonStarr explained, the target is $\wedge^2E$. So, in the end, I think you are asking about a natural map $\wedge^2E \to \wedge^2E$. And the answer to this question is, of course, the identity.

Comment: First, use the fact that $E\otimes E = \mathrm{Hom}(E^*, E)$.  A map $h: E^* \rightarrow E$ induces a map $H: \bigwedge^2E^* \rightarrow \bigwedge^2E$, i.e., $H\in \bigwedge^2E\otimes \bigwedge^2E$.

Comment: This by the way is the Gauss equation that gives the Riemann curvature in terms of the second fundamental form of a hypersurface. Indeed, when the dimension is 2, the result is the determinant of the second fundamental form.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment above, the answer is given by the Gauss equations, which provide a formula for the Riemann curvature tensor in terms of the second fundamental form of a hypersurface in Euclidean space. Here is a description that is more explicit than the ones I gave in my comments above:

Let's view tensor products of $E$ to be multilinear functions of $E^*$. Then the map from $h \in S^2E$ to $R \in S^2\bigwedge^2 E$ is given by
$$
R(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)
= h(v_1,v_3)h(v_2,v_4) - h(v_1, v_4)h(v_2,v_3),
$$
for any $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \in E^*$. Note that, as a bonus, $R$ also satisfies the first Bianchi identities
$$
R(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4) + R(v_2, v_3, v_1, v_4) + R(v_3, v_1, v_2, v_4) = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is what I am looking for. Say that $$h = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ 
b & c
\end{array} \right)$$ (as $2\times 2$ matrix), and set $v_i = (x_i,y_i)$. Then, if I got the computation right, we have $$R(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4) = acx_1x_3y_2y_4-acx_1x_4y_2y_3-acx_2x_3y_1y_4+acx_2x_4y_1y_3-b^2x_1x_3y_2y_4+b^2x_1x_4y_2y_3+b^2x_2x_3y_1y_4-b^2x_2x_4y_1y_3$$                                                 So the tensor $R$ is zero if and only the determinant of $h$ vanishes. Did I get your reasoning right?